Formal solution to large system of equations using Reduce
I'm trying to solve a large system of equations (there are 12 equations with 12 complex variables, hence I'm expecting to be able to write 12 real components as functions of the remaining).
I tried to shrink the code as much as possible, but the idea is that I have three matrix equations (given by eq[X_,Y_,Z_]) and I want to set the system (eq[X,Y,Z] = 0, eq[Y,Z,X] = 0, eq[Z,X,Y] = 0).
I made some initial assumptions since I read it might be helpful, but unfortunately after the first iteration it seems to be struggling already.
Here's the code:
$Assumptions = {a11, a12, a21, a22, b11, b12, b21, b22, c11, c12, c21,
      c22} \[Element] Complexes && {\[Mu]3, f, gs} \[Element] Reals && 
   f > 0 && gs > 0 && \[Mu]3 > 0;

X = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}};
Y =   {{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}};
Z =   {{c11, c12}, {c21, c22}};

eq[X_, Y_, Z_] := 
  CM[CM[X, Y], Y] + CM[CM[X, Z], Z] - 2 I f gs^2 CM[Y, Z];
CM[A_, B_] := A . B - B . A;

(* ----------------- *)

eq[X, Y, Z][[1]][[1]] // FullSimplify;
eq[X, Y, Z][[1]][[2]] // FullSimplify;
(* here I print the i-th entry of the matrix equation and use it to define the functions below. This is to be done for all the 12 equations. *)

func11[a11_, a12_, a21_, a22_, b11_, b12_, b21_, b22_, c11_, c12_, 
   c21_, c22_] := 
  2 (a11 - a22) (b12 b21 + c12 c21) + 
   a21 (-b11 b12 + b12 b22 - c11 c12 + c12 c22) + 
   a12 (-b11 b21 + b21 b22 - c11 c21 + c21 c22) + 
   2 I (b21 c12 - b12 c21) f gs^2;
func12[a11_, a12_, a21_, a22_, b11_, b12_, b21_, b22_, c11_, c12_, 
   c21_, c22_] := 
  a22 b11 b12 - 2 a21 b12^2 - a22 b12 b22 + a22 c11 c12 - 
   2 a21 c12^2 + 
   a12 (2 b12 b21 + (b11 - b22)^2 + 2 c12 c21 + (c11 - c22)^2) - 
   a22 c12 c22 + a11 (-b11 b12 + b12 b22 - c11 c12 + c12 c22) + 
   2 I (b12 c11 - b11 c12 + b22 c12 - b12 c22) f gs^2;

(* ----------------- *)

solv11 = 
  Reduce[func11[a11, a12, a21, a22, b11, b12, b21, b22, c11, c12, c21,
      c22] == 0, a11];

(* now pick the first a11 solution and define A11 = a11, then proceed with another equation *)

A11 = 1/(
   2 (b12 b21 + c12 c21)) (a21 b11 b12 + a12 b11 b21 + 2 a22 b12 b21 -
      a21 b12 b22 - a12 b21 b22 + a21 c11 c12 + a12 c11 c21 + 
     2 a22 c12 c21 - a21 c12 c22 - a12 c21 c22 - 2 I b21 c12 f gs^2 + 
     2 I b12 c21 f gs^2);

solv12 = 
 Reduce[func12[A11, a12, a21, a22, b11, b12, b21, b22, c11, c12, c21, 
    c22] == 0, a12]


But at this point the code is already struggling and I don't see how it can manage to get to the 12th equation.
I'm sure I'm doing it in a very dumb way, but I'm kind of new to mathematica and I know very few techniques to optimise the problem.
Thank you all for the help!
Best
